# Should the snmpEngineID be different for different routers or it depends on the snmp agents?

Tags: snmp, mib

While setting snmpEngineID is it necessary to provide different snmpEngineID for different routers or it depends on the snmp agent that resides on the router?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3411, "Architecture for SNMP Management Frameworks"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3411.txt), states that `snmpEngineId` must be unique for each engine in a network. In practice, that's the same as unique per Agent.

So, if one router has several SNMP agents running on it, each of those agents will have its own `snmpEngineId`.

> 3.1.1.1.  snmpEngineID
>     Within an administrative domain, an snmpEngineID is the unique and
>     unambiguous identifier of an SNMP engine.  Since there is a one-to-
>     one association between SNMP engines and SNMP entities, it also
>     uniquely and unambiguously identifies the SNMP entity within that
>     administrative domain.  Note that it is possible for SNMP entities in
>     different administrative domains to have the same value for
>     snmpEngineID.  Federation of administrative domains may necessitate
>     assignment of new values.